# Interrupt winProgressbar

Tags: r, progress-bar

Do you guys know, if there is any way, to interrupt a winProgressBar?

I tried to press <kbd>Escape</kbd>, but it would not stop the progress bar during calculations.

Thanks for any help

W

Comment: Can't test it as that is a Windows only function, but you could try CTRL+C or CTRL+D.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work. But appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can press `Alt + F4` , just like you would close any program in Windows.